# Unable to get thread dump using jstack

Tags: java, linux, jstack

When I run the command

```
jstack 23264 > threaddump.txt
```

I get:

```
23264: well-known file /tmp/.java_pid23264 is not secure: file should be owned by the current user (which is 0) but is owned by 9001
```

when i ran with `-F` I got

```
Error attaching to core file: cannot open binary file
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue ?
I ran the above command as root

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I need to login as the user associated with process. The root user was not owner of the process. Once I switched the user I was able to get the thread dump.

Comment: In my case on EC2 with Tomcat as the owner following helped:
`sudo -u tomcat jstack -l 2892 > ~/jstack.txt`